# Parsing markers from XML document without use of GXmlHttp

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, getelementsbytagname

I've upgraded most of a Google Maps demo from v2 of the API to v3.

I have a working **Handler.ashx** that returns an XML file from SQL Server data, a snippet of which follows:

```html
<root>
<marker INSTITUTION_KEY="100433" Latitude="40.735772366619301" Longitude="-73.994402766599904" INSTITUTION="New School, The" STREET="65 5th Avenue, Room M107A" CITY="New York" STATE="New York" ZIP="10011" ZIP4="????" WEBSITE="www.newschool.edu">
<Awards AreaID="12" AWARD="N71131B511" WORLDAREA="Western Europe"/>
<Awards AreaID="12" AWARD="N71131B511" WORLDAREA="Western Europe"/>
</marker>
<marker INSTITUTION_KEY="1022" Latitude="25.760174462957600" Longitude="-80.371959517777100" INSTITUTION="Florida International University" STREET="11220 SW 8TH ST" CITY="MIAMI" STATE="FL" ZIP="33184" ZIP4="0000" WEBSITE="www.fiu.edu">
<Awards AreaID="7" AWARD="F91131B511" WORLDAREA="Latin America"/>
<Awards AreaID="7" AWARD="F91131B511" WORLDAREA="Latin America"/>
</marker>
</root>
```

I've read that GXmlHttp no longer exists and I am struggling with trying to convert this code snippet:

```js
var request = GXmlHttp.create();
      request.open("GET", urlRequest, true);
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
              var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;
              var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
              for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

Here is what I have got so far and I am stuck:

```js
//     Load the xml file using ajax 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: urlRequest,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: 
            function (xml) {
                // Parse the xml file and get data
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
                var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null(…)]

Would appreciate a tip on how to make this transition. I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
```

while attempting to create an array called **markers** from the rows with nodes of  **marker**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `$.parseXML` on the result of the `$.ajax` call, when you set `dataType: xml`

from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> "xml": Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.

```
// Read the data
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: true,
  url: urlRequest,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: 
    function (xml) {
      // Parse the xml file and get data
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
```

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_jQueryAjax.html)